# JavaFX Custom Combobox popup "TableView "

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, custom-controls

I want to write a custom JavaFX custom control like DatePicker and ColorPicker, but instead of showing a Calendarview or color palette, i need to show a GridPane that contains a TableView and a TextField. I'm not sure how to make this generic to work with any data model, how i can set columns for the TableView.
for this i have extended from MVC classes (ComboBoxBase,ComboBoxPopupControl,ComboBoxBaseBehavior). But it seems to complicated to me on how to get this custom control implemented correctly.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class ComboBoxTablePopup<S> extends ComboBoxBase {

    /***************************************************************************
     * *
     * Static properties and methods                                           *
     * *
     **************************************************************************/

    private static <T> StringConverter<T> defaultStringConverter() {
        return new StringConverter<T>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(T t) {
                return t == null ? null : t.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public T fromString(String string) {
                return (T) string;
            }
        };
    }

    /***************************************************************************
     *                                                                         *
     * Constructors                                                            *
     *                                                                         *
     **************************************************************************/

    /**
     * Creates a default ComboboxTablePopup instance with an empty
     * {@link #itemsProperty() items} list and default
     * {@link #selectionModelProperty() selection model}.
     */


    public ComboBoxTablePopup() {
        this(FXCollections.<S>emptyObservableList());

    }


    /**
     * Creates a default ComboboxTablePopup instance with the provided items list and
     * a default {@link #selectionModelProperty() selection model}.
     */

    public ComboBoxTablePopup(ObservableList<S> items) {
        setItems(items);
        getStyleClass().add(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
        setEditable(true);
        setPromptText("Plz Search for a pirticular term");


    }


    private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "combobox-table-popup";
    private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<TextField> editor;

    private ObjectProperty<ObservableList<S>> items = new SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<S>>(this, "items");
    public final void setItems(ObservableList<S> value) {
        itemsProperty().set(value);
    }
    public final ObservableList<S> getItems() {
        return items.get();
    }
    public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<S>> itemsProperty() {
        return items;
    }




    // Converter
    public ObjectProperty<StringConverter<S>> converterProperty() {
        return converter;
    }
    private ObjectProperty<StringConverter<S>> converter =
            new SimpleObjectProperty<StringConverter<S>>(this, "converter", ComboBoxTablePopup.<S>defaultStringConverter());
    public final void setConverter(StringConverter<S> value) {
        converterProperty().set(value);
    }

    public final StringConverter<S> getConverter() {
        return converterProperty().get();
    }// Create a symmetric (format/parse) converter with the default locale.




    // Editor
    public TextField getEditor() {
        return editorProperty().get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<TextField> editorProperty() {
        if (editor == null) {
            editor = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<TextField>(this, "editor");
            editor.set(new ComboBoxListViewSkin.FakeFocusTextField());

        }


        return editor.getReadOnlyProperty();

    }


    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new ComboBoxTablePopupSkin<>(this);
    }


}
```

---

```
 public class ComboBoxTablePopupBehavior extends ComboBoxBaseBehavior {
    /**
     * @param comboBox
     */
    public ComboBoxTablePopupBehavior(ComboBoxBase comboBox) {

        super(comboBox, COMBOBOX_TABLE_POPUP_BINDINGS);
    }


    /***************************************************************************
     * *
     * Key event handling                                                      *
     * *
     **************************************************************************/

    protected static final List<KeyBinding> COMBOBOX_TABLE_POPUP_BINDINGS = new ArrayList<KeyBinding>();

    static {
        COMBOBOX_TABLE_POPUP_BINDINGS.add(new KeyBinding(KeyCode.ENTER, "togglePopup"));
        COMBOBOX_TABLE_POPUP_BINDINGS.addAll(COMBO_BOX_BASE_BINDINGS);
    }


}
```

---

public class ComboBoxTablePopupSkin extends ComboBoxPopupControl {

```
private ComboBoxTablePopup comboBoxTablePopup;
private ObservableList<S> comboboxTablePopupItems;

private TextField displayNode;

private TableView<S> tableViewPopupContent;
private ObservableList<S> tableViewItems;


public ComboBoxTablePopupSkin(ComboBoxTablePopup comboBoxTablePopup) {
    super(comboBoxTablePopup, new ComboBoxTablePopupBehavior(comboBoxTablePopup));
    this.comboBoxTablePopup = comboBoxTablePopup;

    updateComboBoxTablePopupItems();

    tableViewPopupContent = createTableView();
    getChildren().add(tableViewPopupContent);

    registerChangeListener(getEditor().textProperty(), "text");

}


@Override
protected Node getPopupContent() {
       return this.tableViewPopupContent;
}

@Override
protected TextField getEditor() {
    return ((ComboBoxTablePopup) getSkinnable()).getEditor();
}

@Override
protected StringConverter getConverter() {
    return ((ComboBoxTablePopup) getSkinnable()).getConverter();
}


@Override
public Node getDisplayNode() {
    if (displayNode == null) {
        displayNode = getEditableInputNode();
        displayNode.getStylesheets().add("ComboBoxTable-display-node");
        updateDisplayNode();
    }

    displayNode.setEditable(comboBoxTablePopup.isEditable());


    return displayNode;


}




@Override
protected void handleControlPropertyChanged(String p) {

    if ("text".equalsIgnoreCase(p)) {
        if (getEditor().textProperty().get().isEmpty()) {
            hide();
        } else
            show();
    } else {
        super.handleControlPropertyChanged(p);
    }

}


public void updateComboBoxTablePopupItems() {
    comboboxTablePopupItems = comboBoxTablePopup.getItems();
    comboboxTablePopupItems = comboboxTablePopupItems == null ? FXCollections.<S>emptyObservableList() : comboboxTablePopupItems;
}


private TableView<S> createTableView() {
    final TableView<S> tableView = new TableView<>();

    tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    tableView.setFocusTraversable(false);

    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(o -> {
        int index = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("selected item changed");
    });


    return tableView;
}
```

}